# How can I use TTL indexes using Prisma and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nestjs, prisma

I want to create a `expires` index in a **MongoDB** collection using [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started). So, that it will automatically remove documents from that collection after a certain amount of time or at a specific clock time.

For example, using **Mongoose** I can do this like below:

```js
  const UserActivity = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      expires: '2m',
      default: Date.now(),
    },
  });
```

With this, the documents will be deleted after 2 minutes of their creation time. I want to do something similar using Prisma. I'm using version: **4.14.0**

Though I have succeeded to add a TTL index using **Prisma Raw Command**, below is an example:

```js
  await this.prisma.$runCommandRaw({
    createIndexes: 'UserActivity',
    indexes: [
      {
        key: {
          createdAt: 1,
        },
        name: 'createdAt_ttl_index',
        expireAfterSeconds: 120,
      },
    ],
  });
```

But I would like to do it at `prisma.schema`, is there any way?

Comment: There has been a 4-year discussion on Github about this, and so far this is not on the Prisma development agenda, even though the subject is already circulating: ```https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/ 5430#```.

Have you managed to find a way to run this command only when a collection is created? Or, when do you use this command that creates the Index? I'm also in the same situation!

Answer (score 1):

Till now, the solution that worked for me for adding a TTL index in MongoDB using Prisma is the **Prisma Raw Command**, below is the example:

```js
  await this.prisma.$runCommandRaw({
    createIndexes: 'UserActivity',
    indexes: [
      {
        key: {
          createdAt: 1,
        },
        name: 'createdAt_ttl_index',
        expireAfterSeconds: 120,
      },
    ],
  });
```

But I'm searching for a faster solution.